# migrating ms access 2003 to ms access 2007

Tags: microsoft-access

I just would like to know what are the things I need to consider before I migrate the databases from ms access 2003 to ms access 2007. 
It seems that the instructions I have here doesn't really help. I'm still kind of stuck-up. I just wanted to have the ms access databases work in the ms access 2007.

Do you have any recommendations? What to consider first?

Thanks

Additional Question:

I've read in the microsoft website on how to convert the database ms access 2003 to ms access 2007. They mentioned here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA102066241033.aspx#3 that you need to install the Access 2000 converter. Is this already integrated in the MS-Access 2003? Or do I have to install it separately?

Thanks again

Additional Question:
hmm that's what I did, I installed MS Access 2007 in other PC and tried to open the .mdb format which is from the MS ACCESS 2003. The problem is I couldn't see the information listed under forms. I think there must be something to do, before you migrate the databases which are made from ms access 2003 to ms access 2007. Do you know any books showing how to do this? Or your ideas are also appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From this article : ["Migrating to Access 2007"](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA102091151033.aspx):

> If you are using Microsoft Office
>   Access 2003, Access 2002, or Access
>   2000, migrating to Access 2007 is
>   easy. Access 2007 supports the Access
>   2002 - 2003 and Access 2000 .mdb file
>   formats so, in most cases, you only
>   need to install Access 2007 and open
>   your Access 2002 - 2003 or Access 2000
>   databases — and you can then use those
>   as you would use an Access 2007
>   database.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I also have it. Additional question, if I migrate the databases from ms access 2003, do I need to convert them to have the file format of .accdb?

Comment: AFAIK, all of Office 2007 is upward compatible. When storing in 2007, you can always choose the 2007 format (the default) or the 2003 format. I haven't used Access since 2003, but the text above says it is entirely compatible with 2003, like the rest of Office 2007.

Comment: i see but in my case it seems that it's not working. btw what do you mean "AFAIK"?

Answer (score 0):

You may run into some issues with combo boxes on existing forms, especially if you have any vb code running from them. Look in the modules for those forms to address any errors.